# delete function in xquery

Tags: xquery

Is there a built-in delete function in `XQuery` that I can use to delete the actual file in the database in a certain directory say `a/b/c/d.xml`

How to implement one if there is no such function?

Answer (score 2):

Deleting a document is implementation dependent. In MarkLogic Server, you would do this:

```
xdmp:document-delete("a/b/c/d.xml")
```

Comment: To delete all documents in MarkLogic: for $doc in collection() return xdmp:document-delete(fn:document-uri($doc))

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this question was posted nearly a year and a half ago, but I thought this would be a helpful contribution.

If you just want to delete a node, you can use this:

```
xdmp:node-delete(/parentNode/childNode)
```

The childNode would be deleted.

See [this link](http://api.xqueryhacker.com/6#xdmp%3anode-delete)

Answer (score 0):

In Zorba and BaseX you would do [file:remove("a/b/c/d.xml")](http://expath.org/spec/file#d2e587) (there are also other processors supporting this module, please add)